inotify limit reached in Docker (k8s)
We have an dotnet6 app that has been running in k8s for quite some time and only recently it started producing the following error, but only on some of the pods.
System.IO.IOException: The configured user limit (512) on the number of inotify instances has been reached, or the per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached.
         at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()

Whenever we rerun the deployment, some pods start up without issue and some fail. deleting the failed ones does not result in new successful pods, the subsequent pods fail as well.
I have tried setting the reloadInChange to false in the AddJosnFile method. I've added:
ENV DOTNET_HOSTBUILDER__RELOADCONFIGONCHANGE=false

to my docker file. I have even tried programmatically setting it at runtime with:
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_hostBuilder:reloadConfigOnChange", "false");

Nothing seems to work. This open GitHub issue exists, but none of the proposed solutions have worked.
Are any other possible solutions not mentioned in the above issue?

I'm new to Stackoverflow so if formatting or any other conventions are not up to standards I apologize in advance...
I encountered a similar problem recently with the inotify instances.
What worked for me was adding the DOTNET_HOSTBUILDER__RELOADCONFIGONCHANGE to the Dockerfile as you suggested yourself. But I'm not sure if you are aware that you can't set ENV variables directly! You can with ARG but not with ENV. See docs; Docker docs .
Furthermore I've put the ENV setting close to the ENTRYPOINT command so it's used in the correct part of the (Multistage) Dockerfile. See an example below.
...
ARG RELOADCONFIGONCHANGE=false
ENV  DOTNET_HOSTBUILDER__RELOADCONFIGONCHANGE=$RELOADCONFIGONCHANGE

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "your_app.dll"]

Hopefully this helps.
